# Telerik, How to export GridView to Excel in these circunstances?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I've read [this official example](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-exporting-data-export-to-excel-via-excelml-format.html) to export to excel in WinForms, If I set the datasource of the RadGridView every works as expected, but If I add manually the columns and if I add manually some rows (`GridViewRowInfo`) then those rows are not exported using this method (only the columns are exported), What I'm missing to export my manually added rows?.

Comment: when you are using a datasource, you add or remove from the datasource not the control; the control is just a viewer in that case, showing what is in the underlying data supplier.  Adding data to a grid wont add (or remove it) from the excel sheet.

Comment: I know that point Plutonix but sorry for my ignorance I don't understand what has to what you've said with the problem that I have exposed, I mean the example does not says "exporting only works with a datasource", nope, I'm just saying that I've tried with both a datasource and the control rows to test the excel export, and it only worked with the datasource set. thanks for comment!

Comment: then, I cannot export the data which is in the "viewer"? could you confirm me that?, the example does not explains anything of this, sorry again for my ignorance...

Comment: I didnt say you could not export it.  If you are using an Excel datasource, you should modify the datasource: add columns etc to the datasource.  True exporting would be starting with new data in a grid add/change/delete as desired then export to an Excel format.

Comment: Maybe I did the wrong question in my last comment, sorry: I can export the data (the rows and its cells) that are displayed in the radgridview with NO datasource set?.

Comment: `if I add manually some rows (GridViewRowInfo) then those rows are not exported` because you added rows to the control not the datasource.  you could import the data, display it, add/change/delete then export; or just add the rows to the datasource

Comment: But I have no datasource in this case...

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me.  If you are not using a DS then where does the data comes from that you are adding TO?

Comment: I just was trying to use the RadGridView.Rows.AddRange method to add a list(of GridVieRowInfo), and when I've tried to export those rows (following the steps of the official example) the resulting xls file only contained the columns

Comment: But no problem, finally I've solved it by using a GridViewDataRowInfo instead GridViewRowInfo. but if you know a better solution (without using a DS) please answer to this question, I'm not sure whether I solved it in the proper way. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a small example in unbound mode and it seems to be exported correctly both rows and columns:

```
        RadGridView grid = new RadGridView();
        grid.Columns.Add("Col1");
        grid.Columns.Add("Col2");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            grid.Rows.Add("cell 1" , "cell 2");
        }

        ExportToExcelML exporter = new ExportToExcelML(grid);
        exporter.RunExport("D:\\test.slx");
```